# Windows 2012 Server with 2 ip address, 2 network interfaces, how to only enable RDP to one address/interface

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

We have a Windows 2012 with 2 IP addresses which are assigned to 2 network interfaces. Currently, we can connect via RDP to both IP addresses on both cards, however, we want to block/disable RDP connections that attempt to connect to one of the addresses/cards (the public network).

I read the [Windows 2008 R2 Server with 2 ip address, how to only enable RDP to one address](https://serverfault.com/questions/483264/windows-2008-r2-server-with-2-ip-address-how-to-only-enable-rdp-to-one-address) and knows that I have to bind the RDP listener port to one of the network cards only but binding RDP listener port command "tsconfig.msc" no longer works on Win2012.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in firewall to accomplish this.

- Open "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"
- Look for the "Remote Desktop - User Mode" rules

For both the **TCP** and **UDP** version, do the following:

- Open the rule
- Switch to the "Scope" tab
- In the "Local IP address" box, select "These IP addresses" (instead of "Any IP address")
- Add the local IP address of the interface you want to use

[image: Windows Firewall rule for RDP]

- Click "OK"